# Water coming out of Bath tap when sink tap turned on

Tags: bathroom, leak, taps

Water is coming out of our bath tap when we turn the sink tap on. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what happens with the quick connects on my outdoor hoses. 
When the pressure drops the washer does not fit tight in the ends and water will leak.
Maybe it has some strange washer that you can try to replace.

Comment: Thank you. Is the pressure drop something we should be worried about?

Comment: Whether your on a home well pump or city water when you open a faucet the pressure is going to drop on that length of pipe (ie running the hot water when someone is in the shower will make the shower colder because of the hot water pressure drops - some new faucets compensate for that now )
some types of washers have a flap that needs a certain amount of pressure to keep them tight.
So the pressure drop is not a problem, in this case, the washer is the problem probably.

Comment: Thank you. Will update tomorrow when we've looked at washers

Comment: It may also be a seat spring failing (these push seals tight against the ball or cartridge), probably best to replace those too.